Server Side Event will not allow client side events to run at the same time
I am attempting to have updates sent whenever they are available from the server utilizing Javascript and PHP. It works as it is supposed to. The basic oulite of the code is as follows
My code simplified looks like this

        var sourceCallUpdater = new EventSource("./js/newmessage2.php");
      
      sourceCallUpdater.addEventListener('NewCall', (e) => {
                   //The returned information is processed and updated to the clients page with code in here
                  
                });


The problem I am having is that while the client is waiting for the server to respond back I can not run any other javascript actions locally. For instance I want to update another part of my page with the following code
function GotoPage(Page) {
        // alert("./pages/" + Page + ".php");

            $.post("./pages/" + Page + ".php", {  },
                    function(data) {
                        $('#Content').html(data);
                        });
                                 
        }

The code works when the client clicks on a button that calls the GotoPage(Page) function, however it will not execute the task until the server has returned the response for the Eventsource called at the start of this question.
Any suggestions. I need to be able to do both at the same time.

what about using web sockets?

This seemed simpler but I am open to doing that way if it doesn't work.

You can try using workers and put the code with EventSource there, but the websockets option looks nicer.

Excuse my ignorance I am not really a programmer but to make a websocket work you need to use a WebSocket server correct? Any suggestions on who to use or how to find some sample code?

Are you using PHP sessions? With the default storage of session data in files, the file gets locked while one script still has access to the session - and all other scripts, that are trying to access the same session, have to wait until the first script is done with it and releases the lock. The solution would be to call session_write_close in your event source script as soon as possible. (If your event source script would need write access to the session during the whole time  it runs, then you'd need something else probably.)

Session_write_close did the trick thank you....
